# data factory multiple activities scheduled daily once not working

Tags: azure-data-factory

After doing multiple tests by making changes to the below pipeline I am posting this in this forum to seek help from the experts out there. The basic idea of the below pipeline is *Activity-1* will do some computation by calling 'U-SQL' script that will output the result to a 'Data Lake store'. Now *Activity-2* will take the data produced from *Activity-1* and copy that data to 'Azure-Sql'. Both the activities are scheduled to run Daily once. However i don't see the pipeline to be triggered ever. If it is scheduled to run for every 15 Minutes it works fine, what am i doing wrong ?

```
{
        "name": "IncrementalLoad_Pipeline",
        "properties": {
            "description": "This is a pipeline to to pick files from Data Lake as per the slice start date time.",
            "activities": [
                {
                    "type": "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL",
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "scriptPath": "andeblobcontainer\\script.usql",
                        "scriptLinkedService": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
                        "degreeOfParallelism": 3,
                        "priority": 100,
                        "parameters": {
                            "in": "$$Text.Format('/Input/SyncToCentralDataLog_{0:dd_MM_yyyy}.txt', Date.AddDays(SliceStart,-7))",
                            "out": "$$Text.Format('/Output/incremental_load/StcAnalytics_{0:dd_MM_yyyy}.tsv', Date.AddDays(SliceStart,-7))"
                        }
                    },
                    "inputs": [
                        {
                            "name": "IncrementalLoad_Input"
                        }
                    ],
                    "outputs": [
                        {
                            "name": "IncrementalLoad_Output"
                        }
                    ],
                    "scheduler": {
                        "frequency": "Day",
                        "interval": 1
                    },
                    "name": "IncrementalLoad",
                    "linkedServiceName": "AzureDataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Copy",
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSource",
                            "recursive": false
                        },
                        "sink": {
                            "type": "SqlSink",
                            "writeBatchSize": 0,
                            "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                        }
                    },
                    "inputs": [
                        {
                            "name": "IncrementalLoad_Input2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "IncrementalLoad_Output"
                        }
                    ],
                    "outputs": [
                        {
                            "name": "AzureSQLDatasetOutput"
                        }
                    ],
                    "scheduler": {
                        "frequency": "Day",
                        "interval": 1
                    },
                    "name": "CopyToAzureSql"
                }
            ],
            "start": "2016-09-12T23:45:00Z",
            "end": "2016-09-13T01:00:00Z",
            "isPaused": false,
            "hubName": "vijaytest-datafactory_hub",
            "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the JSON you've provided above the start and end periods are not big enough. ADF can't provision a set of daily time slices for less than a days time frame.

Try increasing the start and end period to cover 1 week. Eg:

```
        "start": "2016-09-12",
        "end": "2016-09-18",
```

You should be able to extend the end date without dropping the pipeline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Paul, your comments are really help full and made me  re-test the pipeline with the date range as "start": "2016-09-11T00:00:00Z","end": "2016-09-17T00:00:00Z". However when I ran the pipeline the output slices are in "pending execution" state. Also I was expecting the 'start' and 'end' dates as mentioned above should pick '4,5,6,7,8,9,10           sep 2016' files but it has only taken 4,8,9th sep 2016 files. Any help or thoughts on this behavior of pipeline

Comment: @VijayAnde could you also share the JSON for your datasets. There will be something obviously wrong here. It might be worth deleting everything and starting again so time slices are provisioned cleanly. If my above answer was helpful I would appreciate your votes or marking it as accepted.

Comment: hi paul, please find the link of the datasets at [Link](http://imgur.com/a/zWx3H)

Comment: any advice would be of great help.